# Leaking fluid/oil on front left fork

Tags: suspension

I ride a Giant Anthem with Recon Race Rock Shox. I only ride on tar roads so the suspension is disengaged/locked out. I braked to a halt and heard a sharp popping sound, then fluid/oil began to leak out - running freely. My question is whether i need to have this repaired considering the surface I ride on. Would I be damaging the suspension by doing this?

[image]

Pic as requested, trust it will help. I simply need to know if I can the bike without further/any damage to the bike.

Comment: Your options are repair or replace the fork.  Continuing to ride could make it unrepairable, and could fail suddenly and unexpectedly.  Which is the better solution will depend on exactly what is damaged.  Can you add photos of your fork showing as much detail as possible?   And, how often do you service the fork?  Ie has it ever been serviced ?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31158/fork-leaking-oil

Comment: The bike is a hand-me-down, so not sure of history. Its actually the right hand fork thats got the leak. I dont know how to add a photo. the leak is at the orange cover at the bottom of the fork.

Comment: The right fork typically sets the speed of the damping. If there is no oil, no damping and the ride will be very unpleasant if possible at all. Servicing it at home is very complex, you should bring it to a bike shop. The internals may need to be exchanged.